# Dataset get more time to fill data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Stored procedure returns multiple columns and to fill ds get more time.

```
SQL += "exec EquityDealerMapping_TestDJ";
SQL += " @status_id = '" + StrStatusID + "'";
SQL += ", @status_name = '" + StrStatusName + "'";

SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Con);
SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
Cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000;
Da.Fill(_ds);
```

Stored procedure code:

```
select  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Client_code) AS 'SrNo',
    Client_code, Client_name,
    Branch_cd, Trading_Mode,
    Dealer_code_Existing, Dealer_code_New,
    ColorCode
from
    @mytable 
order by 
    Client_code
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: show full code, did you dispose the DataAdapter, your connection. Do you share one sql connection ?

Comment: does not show any error. error in da.fill(ds) it take more time to fill.

Comment: More time in comparison to what? If you execute this query in the query manager, what is the execution time and what is returned data size?

Comment: How big for your table rows? You should tuning on SQL Server site for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way to get more time is to set the CommandTimeout, as you are doing.  Perhaps the problem is somewhere else?

You could try checking the connection state:

```
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken 
      || cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}
```

Another approach to handling queries that return a lot of data is to process a row at a time instead of loading it all into a DataSet or DataTable first.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
foreach (DataRow dr in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
{
    /*this was originally written to handle an arbitrary query, which means
      we might end up with multiple columns with the same name, which isn't allowed.
      use extrachars and n to make names like "ID1", "ID2", etc... */
    string colName = dr["ColumnName"].ToString();
    string extrachars = "";
    int n = 1;
    while (dt.Columns.Contains(colName + extrachars))
    {
        extrachars = n.ToString();
        n++;
    }

    dt.Columns.Add(colName + extrachars, Type.GetType(dr["DataType"].ToString()));
}

while (reader.Read())
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    object[] tempArray = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
    reader.GetValues(tempArray);
    dr.ItemArray = tempArray;

    //either add it to a table
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //or call a function with it
    //SomeFunc(dr);
}
```